How can I change the "After Power Loss" setting in HP BIOS so that the machine automatically starts up when the power is turned on?
I have various HP EliteDesk workstations.
In all the ones I checked, the option "After Power Loss" is grayed out and the value cannot be changed.
How can I change this setting so that the machine automatically starts up when the power is turned on?


Disable all options in "Power Management" in the Advanced tab.
Then "After Power Loss" is open.

